# Is it possible to rephrase for better understanding?

Tags: meaning

I read a book and which contained the following paragraph:

> A special case of data distribution is called the normal distribution,
> also known as the bell curve, which is symmetrical and where the mean,
> median, and mode are identical; **approximately 68% of all the data
> values lie within one plus or minus standard deviation from the mean,
> 95% lie within plus or minus two standard deviations from the mean,
> and nearly all data values lie within plus or minus three standard
> deviations from the mean [41].**

From the word "approximately" to the end I couldn't get the point and meaning. Is is possible to rephrase these four lines (the bold words) to make it clearer?

Comment: If you understand histograms, the diagram at [Analystprep.com/cfa-level... key properties_normal distribution](https://analystprep.com/cfa-level-1-exam/quantitative-methods/key-properties-normal-distribution/) should make it clear.

Comment: Can you double-check that you have transcribed this correctly. For example I believe that, "values lie within one plus or minus standard deviation " should actually be "values lie within plus or minus one standard deviation"

Comment: How is this a proofreading question? The OP is asking for an explanation of a passage in a book that they cannot understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> approximately 68% of all the data values lie within one plus or minus
> standard deviation from the mean, 95% lie within plus or minus two
> standard deviations from the mean, and nearly all data values lie
> within plus or minus three standard deviations from the mean

Let us look at the various terms:

**Approximately**: When you take data values from real life, these are unlikely to fall *precisely* in a normal distribution. The more you take, the more accurate the distribution. For example a million measurements will give a much more precise curve that a hundred, and much, much more than 10 measurements.

I assume that you know what 68% means. It happens to be roughly two thirds.

**Data values**: These are the things being measured. For example if you measure the diameter of one thousand hailstones, you will find one that is the smallest, one that is the largest, and all the others are in between.  With many natural phenomena you will find that there are more in the middle (near the mean) than at the edges. This is what gives rise to the bell curve. It is higher in the middle than at the edges.

**Standard deviation**: This is a technical term and you can look it up in a dictionary or in mathematical terms. The important thing to know is that **it is a unit of measurement**.  A centimeter is a unit that measures length. A gram is a unit that measures weight. A standard deviation is a unit that measures distance from the mean value.

> lie within plus or minus  one  standard deviation from the mean

Some measurements will be ***less*** than the mean. These are the mean ***minus*** some amount. Some measurements will be ***more*** than the mean. These are the mean ***plus*** some amount.

"one  standard deviation from the mean" measures a particular distance from the mean. "Within" indicates that 68% of the measurement are within (inside) that distance.

---

My suggestion is that you search for "normal curve" online. You will find many explanations and they will give the same information but in different words. Some will be easier to read than others.

Comment: I can't bring myself to downvote this, as it's a good explanation, but this sort of question (and by implication, answer) is specifically discouraged on ELU by the close-vote descriptors.

Comment: The calculation of 68% and 95% are mathematical questions. The calculation is not explained in the sentence you ask about. This Stack Exchange is about English Language not about mathematics. Maybe you can get an answer here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/ -  I'll add something about the "lie within ..." phrase in my answer.